# Angular Routing in Rails (shows blank page)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

Hello I'm trying to include Angular in my rails app and I'm getting a blank html
here's my code

> app/views/index.html.erb

```
<body>

    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="view.html">
      <div ng-controller="MainController">This is the view with some data here: {{ somedata }}</div>
    </script>

</body>
```

> assets/javascript/static.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.somedata = "This is some data!"
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'view.html'})
})
```

> application.js

```
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular
//= require_tree .
```

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static#index'
  get '*path' => 'static#index'
end
```

now I whenever I go to server I see a blank page. no errors. I'm using the 'angularjs-rails' gem and it seemed to work fine until I added the angular routes. Could you please point out where is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It :

In your static.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'view.html'})

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
    rewriteLinks: true
  });
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I'm using cloud9 (which is a cloud ide) although I doubt it has anything to do with it.